# $sl_2(\Bbb R)$ is a simple Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $D_n$ be the set of derivations of the form $P(t) \frac{d}{dt}$ , where $P\in \Bbb R[t]\setminus \{0\}$ and $deg\ P\le n$.

Let $∂_2 := t^2 \frac{d}{dt}$ and $∂_1 := 2t \frac{d}{dt}$ and $∂_0 = − \frac{d}{dt}$ be elements of $D_2$.

Prove that $sl_2(\Bbb R)$ is simple.

What I did:

I found an isomorphism from $D_2$ to $sl_2(\Bbb R)$, given by:

$f(∂_1) = H, f(∂_2) = X, f(∂_0) = Y $ where :

$H=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}, X= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, Y= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

Now I am stuck with proving that $D_2$ is simple.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any nonzero ideal of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ contains one of $H$, $X$ and $Y$
As $[H,aH+bX+cY]=2bX-2cY$ and $[H,[H,aH+bX+cY]]=4bX+4cY$ then if $I$
is an ideal of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $aH+bX+cY\in I$ then $aH\in I$,
 $bX\in I$ and $cY\in I$.

If $H\in I$ then $[H,X]=2X\in I$ and $[H,Y]=-2Y\in I$ so that
$I=\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

If $X\in I$ or $Y\in I$ then $H=[X,Y]\in I$.

All this is in textbooks on Lie algebras.

Comment: Actually I thought I could prove it using the isomorphism $sl_n\cong D_n$ but this is an elegant proof. Thank you!